# I am getting an error when I use the remote-container plugin for VS Code to connect to a remote Linux docker container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, remote-containers

my environment

- VS Code: 1.68.1
- remote-containers: v0.238.2
- Docker: 20.10.17
- Linux(Server): Linux version 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 (mockbuild@kbuilder.bsys.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Nov 8 23:39:32 UTC 2018
- Windows10(Client)：21H1

The container can be built normally, but cannot be started, the following is the error message：

```bash
[19775 ms] trap "exit 0" 15
[19775 ms] exec "$@"
[19775 ms] while sleep 1 & wait $!; do :; done -
[19775 ms]     at NR (c:\Users\Administrator\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.238.2\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:239:1572)
[19775 ms]     at Jy (c:\Users\Administrator\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.238.2\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:239:1510)
[19776 ms]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[19776 ms]     at async zR (c:\Users\Administrator\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.238.2\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:245:2006)
[19776 ms]     at async nb (c:\Users\Administrator\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.238.2\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:245:3110)
[19776 ms]     at async JR (c:\Users\Administrator\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.238.2\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:245:13046)
[19776 ms]     at async KR (c:\Users\Administrator\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.238.2\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:245:12802)
[19785 ms] Exit code 1
[19790 ms] Command failed: D:\app\vscode\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe c:\Users\Administrator\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.238.2\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\data --workspace-folder d:\vscodework\mslearn-python-products --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=d:\vscodework\mslearn-python-products --log-level debug --log-format json --config d:\vscodework\mslearn-python-products\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true
```